# Read URI on Android

Tags: android, uri

I'm trying to read website data with my Android app. What's strange is that it works on my Android 2.3.4 phone, but not my brand new 2nd Gen Nexus 7 Tablet that's running Android 4.3. I'm not getting any errors in LogCat, there's just nothing displayed on the Tablet. Has anyone else run into this? If so, clue me in to a fix so that it'll run on both my devices. Here's my whole Activity:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WCBCCalendar extends Activity {
Button back_BTN;
TextView urlTest_TV;
String about_url_Str = "http://www. url to read";
String returned;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
    back_BTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backCal_btn);
    sunDate_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sunDate_TV);
    npDate_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.npDate_TV);
    urlTest_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.urlTest_tv);

    GetWebInfo test = new GetWebInfo();
    try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        urlTest_TV.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}// --- END onCreate

// --- Classes, Methods

public class GetWebInfo {
    public String getInternetData() throws Exception{
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI(about_url_Str);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity        ().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while((l = in.readLine()) !=null ){
                sb.append(l + nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        }finally{
            if (in != null){
                try{
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }//--- END class

// --- END all Classes, Methods

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
}

}
```

Comment: because you are doing network operations on UI Thread probably you are getting `..doing to much work on UI Thread..` in log. so use `AsyncTask` to do run operation in background thread

Comment: See Android documentation for details: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html